# Passing data between two tables using segue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, tableview, segue

I have two tables and a viewcontroller, one carries categories (Capital cities, Large Cities, Small Cities) and when you click on any category, it gives you details of each e.g
capital cities - (London, New York, Paris, Ottawa) and when you click details it gives you maps (view controller)

I have created an array on details table such as

```
    NSArray *CapitalCities =[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"London", @"New York",
    @"Paris", @"Ottawa", nil]

      NSArray *LargeCities=another array etc
```

I have a integer property on details city known as rowNumber, to keep track of which row was clicked and list corresponding arrays

WHere I am getting problem is segue

Since segue only works when the source is embedded in navigation controller, it means table 1 and table 2 are both embedded in navigation controller except viewcontroller

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showList"]){




        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTable indexPathForSelectedRow];

        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController
        *)segue.destinationViewController;
        CategoryViewController *destViewController = 
          (CategoryViewController*)navController.topViewController;


        NSString *myCategory=[categoriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        if ([myCategory isEqualToString:@"capital cities"])
        { 
       //make row number 0 so that you can load capitalCities array
          destViewController.rowNumber = 0;
             } if (([myCategory isEqualToString:@"Small Cities"]))
          {
          // make row number so that you can load small cities array on the next page
          destViewController.rowNumber = 1;
          }
```

The next page

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  
     (NSInteger)section
      {
       if(rowNumber==0)
       {
        return capitalCities.count;
        }else
         return other arrays
```

This does not work, any clues?

Comment: The best approach would be to follow an MVC architecture, and then just initialize your view controllers with the same model for all relevant screens. If you do it the segue, then you can say that you "pass" the model from VC to VC, meaning that you only have to pass one variable regarding the data, and the same each time. Makes for understandable code.

Comment: I'm afraid that that is outside the scope of this site, but I'm sure you can find many examples and tutorials around if you search a bit. BTW, MVC stands for Model-View-Controller, to help your search. Anyway, Apple's article is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html

Comment: This going around in circles, but just to be clear, I was referring to the use of MVC in stead of just passing raw data between view controllers. Regarding how to initialize a view controller from a segue, I am sure that there is plenty of information on this and other sites, including Apple's own.